# Explanation of the output of the multivariate randn

Tags: c++, opencv, random, gaussian

I would like to understand one thing:
We suppose to have three variables `(X, Y, Z)` and we want to calculate the covariance matrix between them.
We get a mean and a covariance. Now I want to generate samples from it, using the `randn` function. In the `randn` function, as stated in the documentation:

```
dst - output array of random numbers; the array must be pre-allocated and have 1 to 4 channels.
```

My vector `dst` must necessarily be set up as a 3-channel matrix to work. Should I set it this way because I have 3 variables `(X, Y, Z)`?
And if I had more than 4 variables, like: `X, Y, Z, W, R, T ...`
How could I do?
This is the code I used:

```
cv::Mat dst = cv::Mat::zeros(2,2, CV_32FC3);
cv::theRNG().state = cv::getTickCount();
cv::randn(dst, mean, covar);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to opencv documentation cv::randn uses mean and standard deviation of generated numbers. You should use sqrt(variance) instead of covariance in this generator.

Comment: I need to generate samples from a multivariate gaussian distribution. I red that it is possbile with randn. Isn't it?

Comment: It is possible, but you should use matrix of varainces instead of covariance.

Comment: ok, but I asked another thing. i.e: the channel and observation dimension